# How to replace all strings in an array to a specific special character

Tags: java, arrays, string, javafx, special-characters

I am using JavaFX and I am currently in a project which I have to create the hangman game. I have a Text Field and a Label displaying 1 word from an array whenever I click the button "Start Game". So, whenever I click "Start Game", let's say the string "School" is generated. It will show in the Text Field and in the Label. Instead of showing the actual string, I would like to replace the string to a special character. I would like to have the Text Field showing '*' and the Label showing '_' of the length of the string so "School" would be "******" in Text Field and "_ _ _ _ _ _" in Label. How do I do that?

*My code is functional, I just don't know how to replace the string to special character*

This is my code from the controller

// list of words in Array

```
String[] listWords = {"Tuesday", "School", "Dog", "Vehicle", 
             "Bird", "Book", "Recipe", "Sun", "Hammer", "Orange"};
```

// For loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listWords.length; i++) {
     String randomWords = listWords[(int)(Math.random() * listWords.length)];                                   
     TxtField.setText(randomWords);
     wordLabel.setText(randomWords); 
     }
```

I tried to follow a bunch of videos from YouTube but there's not one showing with a string of array. Most of them are using ArrayList or List which I'm not using. I tried to google and their examples are also not showing how to do it from an array.

Comment: use a regex string::replaceAll

Comment: I would suggest completing a console version of the game. When that is complete, work on the graphics.

Comment: Remember to look at your post after you submit so you can [edit] any mistakes: code blocks use _three_ backticks, not four.

Comment: Given example code for an `ArrayList`, you should be able to easily convert the example to use an array, if you understand arrays and `ArrayList`. But, a `List` is more flexible than an array. For one, the size of an array is fixed, but the size of an `List` can be changed. You can delete elements from a `List` but not an array. (Drifting off-topic: If you have an array of Objects, you can set an element to `null` to simulate deletion. If you have an array of primitives, to simulate deletion, you might have a "special value" that indicates the indexed element is invalid.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is very basic logic using `for`:

```java
String replaceString = "*";
String[] maskedListWords = new String[listWords.length];

for (int i = 0; i < listWords.length; i++) {
    maskedListWords[i] = listWords[i].replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", replaceString);
}

for (String string : maskedListWords) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Single string

### Option 1: Just create one

It's a programming language, not an assistant. You sometimes have to think slightly creatively to get the job done. Instead of 'replacing every character', why not just make a new string? You know the length..

```
public static String starred(String input) {
  char[] starred = new char[input.length()];
  Arrays.fill(starred, '*');
  return new String(starred);
}
```

### Option 2: Regular expressions

`replaceAll` accepts a regular expression which is a mini-programming language very unlike java for text matching; it is only useful for regular grammars (you can't parse java code with it, for example), but this is very simple. `.` is regexp-ese for 'any character'. Thus:

```
public static String starred(String input) {
  return input.replaceAll(".", "*");
}
```

### All strings

That doesn't seem right - replacing that string array with stars would destroy the words and you need them to know if the user entered a correct letter. You'd want to get 1 word from your array of possible words to play with and then keep that around, and make a copy with the stars in.

### Generally replacing 1 character

Strings are immutable; you cannot change them. But you can make *new* strings based off of old ones. Or, in this case, a lot simpler, make a mutable thing so you can just replace characters (presumably you'd want to replace stars with letters as the user guesses correctly):

```
List<String> POSSIBLE_WORDS = List.of("Tuesday", "School", ....);
Random rnd = new Random();

String word = POSSIBLE_WORDS.get(rnd.nextInt(POSSIBLE_WORDS.size());
char[] letters = new char[word.length()];
Arrays.fill(letters, '*');
// show to the user

// if user guesses a letter:

char guessedLetter = 'e'; // get user input here.
if (!alreadyGuessed.contains(guessedLetter)) {
  boolean matched = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) == guessedLetter) {
      letters[i] = word.charAt(i);
      matched = true;
    }
  }

  if (!matched) hangALittleMore();
  alreadyGuessed.add(guessedLetter);
}
```

And so on.

Comment: And my personal favourite: use a hashmap.

Comment: Sorry, sometimes thinking a little bit more doesn't cut it as of now for me. I've just enrolled in programming 3 months ago and I have 0 knowledge in the field. But thank you for your help. It should work!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
String guesses; // characters guessed so far
String word; // the word to be guessed
```

Then to mask all un-guess characters in word with `*`:

```
String display = word.replaceAll("[^" + guesses + "]", "*");
```

This builds a negative character class from the guesses, eg the regex `[^abcd]` would match any character *not* a, b, c or d.